# How to avoid this undesired vertical space in the IEEEtran table environment?

Tags: tables, ieeetran, vertical-spacing

I need to collect some tables in one table environment and use the standard \caption command to caption each of them.  My MWP:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,journal,twocolumn,10pt,final]{IEEEtran}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\begin{document}%

\title{Sophisticated Table Test}
\author{Author Author}
\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00~\copyright~20XX IEEE}
\maketitle

\begin{table*}[t]
\caption{Top Two-Column Table A}%
\includegraphics[viewport=0pc 0pc 43pc 5pc, clip=true, draft]{sizetest-texpica}%
\caption{Top Two-Column Table B}%
\includegraphics[viewport=0pc 0pc 43pc 5pc, clip=true, draft]{sizetest-texpica}%
%%
\vskip 0pt %% <-- could be replaced by \par but anyway results in an undesired extra vspace 
%%
\valign{\hsize=\columnwidth#\cr%
\caption{Bottom One-Column Table C}%
\includegraphics[viewport=0pc 0pc 21pc 5pc, clip=true, draft]{sizetest-texpica}\cr%
\noalign{\hfill}%
\caption{Bottom One-Column Table D}%
\includegraphics[viewport=0pc 0pc 21pc 5pc, clip=true, draft]{sizetest-texpica}\cr%
}%\valign
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

The result tables are aligned the following (excerpt from page 2 of the MWP) :

[image]

My problem is the extra vertical space added between the body of table B and the captions of tables C and D.  My questions are:

- How can i avoid this space? (i need the same space as between the body of table A and the caption of table B)
- If i cannot avoid it, how can at least compensate it using strict, meaningful measures, not a guessing?
- That is the source (cause) of this extra space? Why such a space is avoided between tables A and B, but not between tables B and C/D?

Beforehand thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try `setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}` in your preamble.

Comment: Unless the IEEEtran manual says you can mess with \abovecaptionskip (and it coesn't), don't do it!

Comment: The spacing between two floats is given by `\floatsep` and `\dblfloatsep`.  If anything, I would throw in a `\vskip\dblfloatsep` before the second `\caption`.